# Float submit on right

Tags: html, css

I've got an input field and a submit button.

When I float the submit button right, I want it to end at the same point as the input field does - here's an example of what I mean: http://prntscr.com/aggln5

Currently, the input and submit end at different points: https://jsfiddle.net/9mjrz05o/

```
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="float: right;">
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? How to extend the `<input />` elements, or how to position the button to line up with the end of the input's current position?

Comment: how to position the button to line up with the end of the input's current position

Answer (score 1):

Set input width as 100%

```
input[type="text"]{
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9mjrz05o/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use this..
You need to clear the float so i have added  `form:after{ ... }`

```
#container {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

    input[type="text"]{
      display: block;
      width:100%;
    }
    form{
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    form:after
    {
      content:'.';
      position:relative;
      clear:both;
      visibility:hidden;
      height:0px;
    }

    input[type="submit"]
     {
        width:70px;
     }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

Set `input {display: inline-block; }` and `#container { text-align: right; }`

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/s6h7of5p/

Comment: That puts the input and submit next to each other though

Comment: I changed my answer, see above

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float property from the submit button, and add this line to the input part of the CSS:

```
margin-left:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/9mjrz05o/2/

I've added the following CSS

```
#container {
    background: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
}

input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

form {
    height: 100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `display: inline-flex` on `form`. So if you change width on text input `submit` input will always be aligned to right side of text input as you can see here [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/202/)

```css
#container {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

form {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Or you could also do this with `display: inline-block` on  `form` and `float: right` on **submit** `input`

```css
#container {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove br from the HTML and give the inline-block display to form and block display to input.

```
#container {
    background: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    }
    form{
      display:inline-block
    }

    input {
      display: block;
    }
```